# Integrating $\int^\infty_ 0\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2} - 1}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I integrate
$$\int^{\infty}_ 0 \frac{x^2}{{e^{x^2}} - 1}\,\mathrm{d}x?$$

I have tried using the Gaussian Integral Formula and Integration by parts, but have made no progress so far.

Comment: I tried using the Gaussian Integral formula, and Integration by parts?

Comment: Well, include anything you have tried in the question by clicking "edit".

Comment: you can multiply by $e^{-x^2}/e^{-x^2}$ to see what it can make appear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using that

$$\frac1{e^{x^2}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx^2}$$

it follows that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\underbrace{\int_0^\infty e^{-nx^2}x^2\,dx}_{=\sqrt{\pi}/(4n^{3/2})}
=\frac{\sqrt\pi}4\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^{3/2}}
=\frac{\sqrt\pi}4\zeta\left(\frac32\right)$$

*Edit*: the calculation of

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-nx^2}x^2\,dx$$

can be done using the classical result $\int_0^\infty e^{-n x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}/(2\sqrt{n})$ with $n>0$. Indeed,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-nx^2}x^2\,dx
=-\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dn}e^{-nx^2}\,dx
=-\frac{d}{dn}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{n}}
=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4 n^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: It would make the answer complete if you can show the derivation of the closed form of the integral(the last one) by differentiation under the integral sign and Gaussian integral. By the way, quick and nice answer! {+1}

Comment: @Szeto Thanks! I've added the calculation of that integral

Comment: :) Actually I thought this integral can only be done by residue method. Your approach beats me!

Comment: Next we can have fun doing
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3\;dx}{e^{x^2}-1} = \frac{1}{2}\;\zeta(2)
\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4\;dx}{e^{x^2}-1} = \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\;\zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)
\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5\;dx}{e^{x^2}-1} = \zeta(3)
$$

Comment: @GEdgar Why don’t you generalize it for $x^k$?

Comment: Even try $x^k$ where $k$ is not an integer.  Get not only $\zeta$ but also $\Gamma$ in the answer.  Those $\sqrt{\pi}$ we see are actually $\Gamma$ function values.

Comment: Mathematica says for: $m\leq n$ is :$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{\exp \left(x^m\right)-1} \, dx=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1+n}{m}\right)
   \text{Li}_{\frac{1+n}{m}}(1)}{m}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk and $\text{Li}_p(1)$ is just $\zeta(p)$

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, I'll have fun generalizing the result to

$$I(s)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^s}{e^{x^2}-1}\,dx \qquad s\in\mathbb{C}, \text{Re }(s)> 1$$
We'll expand the denominator into a geometric series before using the Gamma function to evaluate the final integral:

\begin{align}
I(s)&=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^s}{e^{x^2}-1}\,dx \\ 
&=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^s e^{-x^2}}{1-e^{-x^2}}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^{+\infty} x^s e^{-x^2} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} e^{-nx^2},dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} x^s e^{-x^2} e^{-nx^2},dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} x^s e^{-x^2(n+1)},dx \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} x^s e^{-nx^2}dx \qquad u=x^2\\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} u^{s/2} e^{-nu} \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} u^{(s-1)/2} e^{-nu}\,du \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{(s+1)/2}}\\ \\
I(s)&=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right) \zeta\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Thus, for $s\in\mathbb{C}, \text{Re }(s)>1$,

\begin{align}
\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^s}{e^{x^2}-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right) \zeta\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}
\end{align}